# BNF (EBNF) to describe table format with optional columns

Tags: context-free-grammar, bnf, ebnf, context-sensitive-grammar

Im trying the define a grammar that can be used to describe the following type of table:

**co1.......**col2.....**col3......

value.......value.......value

value.......value.......value

value.......value.......value

value.......value.......value

.....

[image: picture of table]

with **col1 and **col2 being column names. The format can optionally have additional, predefined columns (eg. let's assume **col4 and **col5 can also be included). I want to write a parser that outputs this format. Can this type of table be described using BNF or EBNF?

From what I have read so far, this is a context-sensitive grammar and thereby cannot be described by BNF or EBNF (I assume this is because row x will only include **col4 if x-1 did so as well). Is this correct? Are there any alternatives to describe the table format above?

Comment: I feel like you're overthinking this. Presumably there is some delimiter between columns in a row. Just split the columns on that delimiter. What do you need to accomplish that can't be done by splitting by delimiters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a variable number greater than two of columns which must have the same number of entries, or a variable number greater than two of rows that must have the same number of entries, the language cannot be context-free for the same reason `a^n b^n c^n` is not context-free.

If you want an unrestricted grammar for tables, something like this would work:

```
// begin with A^n B
  S := AS | AB

// produce C^n D^n B
  A := CD               
 DC := CD

// produce C^n . E^n B
 DB := BE
CBE := C.EB
 BE := EB

// produce C^n . E^n G^n B
  E := EG
 GE := EG

// produce C^n (. E^n)+ B
 GB := BE
EBE := E.EB
 BE := EB

// produce C^n (. E^n)+
  B := (empty)

// lead column headings and values to terminal symbols
  C := (rules for headers)
  E := (rules for values)
```

The above assumes all values are of one type, for simplicity; that is, all values can be generated using the rule for `E`. If you want to add multiple types and coordinate with the columns involved, the grammar becomes more complicated (you need `E`, `E'`, `E''`, etc., one for each value type, and corresponding `G`, `G'`, `G''`, etc. and `C`, `C'`, `C''`, etc., and duplicate productions to handle moving `B` around each one, but otherwise the process remains similar; and then your grammar would produce only tables with proper type matches).